# Can a programmer set the number of clock cycles used to execute an instruction?

Tags: assembly, clock, frequency

I'm using a HCS12 mirco-controller from freescale and a question was brought up. What effects the time delay? I said the crystal frequency and the type of compiler being used. I know that I can set a different frequency by accessing the functionality of two pins that control the clock source called XTAL and EXTAL.

My main question is as the title says "Can I set the number of clock cycles used to execute a given intruction?". I just don't understand the question and what it is asking. How can I set a clock cycle for an instruction or dictate how many their are for an instruction. An instruction like in Assembly has a predefined number of clock cycles it takes to execute. For example the no operation "NOP" instruction wastes one clock cycle. So the only way I would know how to change this is to change the frequency making it shorter or longer in duration which will change the number of clock cycles to execute an instruction. Am I on track here or am I losing my mind?

Comment: Who asked you this question? SO is not particularly suited for the question about the question, but this one is pretty clear.

Comment: "affect", not "effect".

Comment: I do not know that processor, but some instructions, such as a DIV could take many more cycles if it has to process larger numbers. The DIV generally uses a loop to process each bit one after the other.

Comment: Why is this tagged `crystal-reports`?

Answer (score 4):

Each opcode uses a set amount of clock cycles. You can not set this, it is a hardware restriction.

If you change the clock frequency, it will not change the number of cycles it takes to execute a opcode. It will only change how long it takes.

Comment: If you want some dead cycles you'll need something like: `asm("nop");`